# Lazarus Pascal setting value from a textbox

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I have to set up some sql queries.

The command I want to enter is `INSERT INTO tblTest VALUES (1);`

Here is my code

```
SQLQuery1.SQL.text:=('INSERT INTO tblTest VALUES (' (enterid.text) ')' );
```

`enterid` is my textbox that I wish to input a number or name into

How would I get the brackets before and after it to create my command?

Comment: Use the `+` operator to concatenate. Any text book will tell you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two problems with your code. The entire SQL statement is bracketed which is wrong (at least, it's wrong in Delphi, so I assume that it's also wrong in Lazarus. Secondly, the 'values' statement doesn't need the brackets and is liable to store the literal string, "enterid.text".

Better to write like this:

```
SQLQuery1.SQL.text:= 'INSERT INTO tblTest VALUES (:p1); 
SQLQuery1.params[0].asstring:= enterid.text;
// alternatively SQLQuery1.ParamByName ('p1').asstring:= enterid.text;
SQLQuery1.execsql;
```